# Selecting checkboxes around a select all div

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to check all checkboxes located in a div when a user clicks the select all button (also in the same div). I want to use jQuery to achieve this. My HTML code looks like this:

```
 <div>
     <input type='checkbox' name='select_all' />
     <input type='checkbox' name='check1' />    
     <input type='checkbox' name='check2' />   
     <input type='checkbox' name='check3' />   
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do something like this to select checkbox inside one div and not all checkboxes:
If you check the select all, it will select all checkboxes, if you uncheck the select all, it will  uncheck all select boxes.

http://jsfiddle.net/y7RsB/

```
$("input[name=select_all]").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',$(this).prop("checked") ? true : false);
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/y7RsB/) a live example

```
<div>
  <input type='checkbox' name='select_all' />
  <input type='checkbox' name='check1' />    
  <input type='checkbox' name='check2' />   
  <input type='checkbox' name='check3' />   
</div>  ​

$(document).on('change', '[name="select_all"]', function(){
      var $this = $(this); 
      var div = $this.parent();
      var ischecked = $this.prop('checked');
      div.find(':checkbox').not($this).prop('checked', ischecked);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the other responses are correct, I would like to add something: If there are other checkboxes in the HTML page, by selecting checkboxes only by the type (checkbox), you might check other checkboxes unrelated to the ones you want.

A minimum of added code, that shouldn't affect your other code parts is to assign the checkboxes a specific class. For example, if your checkboxes represent hobbies, you add them the hobby_checkbox class:

```
 <div>
     <input type='checkbox' name='select_all' /> Select all hobbies
     <br>
     <input type='checkbox' class='hobby_checkbox' name='check1' /> Ski   
     <br>
     <input type='checkbox' class='hobby_checkbox' name='check2' /> Travel
     <br>
     <input type='checkbox' class='hobby_checkbox' name='check3' /> PC Games
     <br>
     <br>
     <input type='checkbox' class='other_checkbox' name='other_check' /> Subscribe
 </div>
```

Then, when you want to select the checkboxes you want to check, you select only the ones belonging to the class you want:

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="select_all"]', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var div = $this.parent();
      var ischecked = $this.prop('checked');
      div.find(':checkbox.hobby_checkbox').prop('checked', ischecked);

});
```

This avoids checking the subscribe checkbox which is unrelated.

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8kvdM/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=select_all]').click(function(){
  $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In adding to prev answer:

```
$('input[name=select_all]').on('click', function(){

    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
         $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
    }else{
         $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```